# How to pass only options with the CMD command?

Tags: docker

Suppose there's an image outside of my control that specifies custom entry point. Let's call it `server`

```
# server's Dockerfile

ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/server
```

I'm building an image based on the server. I'd like to specify a default command to be executed. It should call the server's entrypoint and pass an argument to it. The argument is a single option. A naive solution would look like this:

```
FROM server:latest

CMD --port 8080
```

That, however, fails during `docker build` with

```
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 3: Unknown flag: port
```

How can I use CMD to pass arguments to entry point that start with `--`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands are defined like:

```
CMD [ "--port", "8080" ]
```

Where otherwise the `--port` gets attached to the CMD command itself as a flag, not the actual command it runs.

This presumes that the `ENTRYPOINT` can properly handle just options and doesn't require a path of an executable as is traditionally the case.

Comment: Sorry for your initial confusion. I edited the question to use more specific example which hopefully conveys my goal better.

Comment: Notice the `[ ... ]` formatting I've used here. It's important to help Docker distinguish what's what. If you omit it, as I said, the `--` argument is interpreted as a flag to `CMD`, which is not what you want.